# How to set padding-left to my custom textbox in css?

Tags: asp.net, css

How to set padding-left to my custom textbox in css? Thanks.

Comment: Um... just set the property? Can you show some code? What do you mean by custom textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the browser/version, form controls might not obey the normal CSS properties ... because the browser might implement them using the standard O/S-specific CSS-unaware GUI controls.